# informatica powercenter FTP issue

Tags: ftp, informatica-powercenter

I'm facing an issue on a FTP I would like to know how, and the best option for the below situation.

I'm dealing with a process that connects via FTP and gets a file, using JMS on Informatica Powercenter.

I would like to know if there is a way to get the log saying that there was a problem on the connection and rerun the process, via a unix script

or

I would like to know if there is a way to detect the issue on the INFORMATICA Workflow itself and rerun the process.

Answer (score 2):

I use SCP and i never have problems, ex:

```
scp username@ host:Sourcefile Destinationfile
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
echo "Connected and copied the file”
else
echo "ERROR in copying the file using SCP "
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively `grep` for particular ERROR message/code in the workflow/session log file. If the `grep` returns something then there is a problem.

You have have a command line task after your session in the workflow and then perform this action.